# Tab menu with menu items having the same outcome

Tags: jsf, primefaces, highlight, tabmenu

I'm using PrimeFaces `<p:tabMenu>`. Two of my menuItems have the same outcome with different URL parameters.

The behavior is the following : 
When I click on each item, I'm redirected to the right page (In this example: `foo.xhtml` with two different f values). However only the first tab is highlighted.

```
<p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{activeIndex}" styleClass="menuPanel">
        <p:menuitem value="foo" outcome="/pages/foo.xhtml?f=all">
        </p:menuitem>
        <p:menuitem value="bar" outcome="/pages/foo.xhtml?f=me">
        </p:menuitem>
        <p:menuitem value="hi" outcome="/pages/hi.xhtml">
        </p:menuitem>
</p:tabMenu>
```

Do you know how I could make the second tab work as expected, i.e. be highlighted whenever clicked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you set the activeindex? Activeindex controls the Highlighting. Set into your bean from foo.xhtml the right activeindex.

Comment: Hello jklee and thank you for your answer. I'm quite new to the JSF world. I finally solved the problem using this into the foo.xhtml managed bean :

`<ui:param name="activeIndex" value="#{fooBean.activeIndex}" />`

And then implement a getter of activeIndex based on `RequestHelper.getRequestParameter("f")`. Every other attempt failed and the menu was not synchronized with the user's choice. Do you think this is the right way to go ? -- Seems a little odd to me...

Comment: Setting the activeIndex is always a bit difficult. I do not know a general solution. Often I use f:viewParam for get/set it http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.de/p/view-parameters-in-jsf-20.html